# German pronunciation of English words

Tags: pronunciation

Anglicisms are common in German, but often they don't follow either the usual German pronunciation rules or the English pronunciation. Examples (pronunciations use [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)):

TV Series (English) / TV-Serie (German)

- English pronunciation: /tiː'viː'sɪɹiz/
- French pronunciation of the word "série": /se'ʁi/
- German pronunciation: /tifau'sɛʁiə/
- German pronunciation if German pronunciation rules were followed: /tefauzeːʁiə/  (as "serie" is pronounced in "Fernsehserie")

Computer

- English pronunciation: /kəmpjutə/ (UK) , /kəmpjuɾəɹ/ (US)
- German pronunciation: /kɔmpjuːtɐ/
- German pronunciation if German pronunciation rules were followed: /kɔmputɐ/

Band (musical group)

- English pronunciation: /bænd/ (US)
- German pronunciation: /bænt/
- German pronunciation if German pronunciation rules were followed: /bant/

Sandwich

- English pronunciation: /sændwɪt͡ʃ/
- German pronunciation: /sentwit͡ʃ/ , /sentvit͡ʃ/
- German pronunciation if German pronunciation rules were followed: /zantviç/

I've seen this inconsistency in other languages in which most native speakers are not familiar with English, but that is not the case in Germany. Is there a reason for this mix between English and German in the pronunciation of these words?

Comment: Who the heck says /tifau'sɛʁiə/?

Comment: I'm not convinced there really are "rules" as such for borrowed words. I think in general German likes to stick to the original pronunciation more than English, but there are many other factors involved. Are the sounds that don't exist in the borrowing language? Would the spelling be difficult to interpret? Was the word recently borrowed or has it been around for a while. German also combines native and foreign components, e.g. "ausflippen". A lot of these words are from youth culture, and I'm pretty sure the kids aren't that interested in "rules".

Comment: @Janka slowgerman.com/2024/02/06/die-tv-serie-der-bergdoktor-sg-265 . Hearing it again, I'm not sure if the S in "Serie" is pronounced /z/ or /s/ anymore.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista it is also Tefau-Serie there, not Tifau-Serie. It would've been extremely odd to pronounce the T as English and the V as German. Maybe the "die" in "die TV-Serie" tripped you up here.

Comment: @Chieron I hear /i/ instead of /e/ (the same phonem of the first vowel in "Serie") in the first syllable of "TV" in the link above and in https://forvo.com/search/tv-serie/. I hear the exactly same vowel said in https://forvo.com/word/tea/. Maybe it's a problem with my hearing.

Comment: "Fominta" clearly has a southern German accent and says [s] instead of the standard [z] at the onset of Serie; "Thonatas" speaks very unnaturally, there should be no [ɛ] in Serie.

Comment: @Alan I think it’s your hearing. In the SlowGerman link, I very clearly and distinctly hear /te'fauˌzeːʁiə/.

Comment: @Raketenolli I don’t hear an /ε/ in Thonatas’ pronunciation either – I hear an [r-affected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_German_phonology#endnote_1) /eː/, the sequence being phonetically something like [e͡ɐʁ]. It’s just the tongue moving downwards and backwards a bit in preparation for the uvular/pharyngeal [ʁ].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is the T in the "TV" word in the SlowGerman link pronounced as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpBPaDI5IgI ? Is there any chance the E vowel is pronounced differently (e.g. /ɪ/) when it's short instead of long (as in Tee) ?

Comment: @Alan You mean when she says the name in isolation at 1:18? That has a long vowel, as it would normally when stressed. In _TV_, it’s unstressed and tends to get shortened (as in the SlowGerman sample), but that doesn’t change the quality, at least not to the extent that it merges with /ɪ/. Of course, [e] and [ɪ] aren’t _that_ far apart to begin with, but they are distinct. In the SlowGerman sample, I’d say she maintains a shortened, but still quite clear [e].

Comment: Yes, I meant the T pronounced in isolation at 1:18. I hear a difference in the quality of the E vowel pronounced there and in the "TV" pronunciation in SlowGerman. It seems I'm the only one, so never mind.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The basic pronunciation rule for English (and French and Italian) loan words in German is “take the original pronunciation (not the spelling!) and adapt it to standard German phonology (*)”. Let's take “Band” (musical group) as an example: The English pronunciation is /bænd/. The German pronunciation is what you get if the phonemes of /bænd/ are replaced by their closest relatives (**) in German: First, there is no /æ/ in German, so it's replaced by /ɛ/. Second, there are no final voiced plosives in (most variants of) German, so /d/ is unvoiced to /t/. The result is /bɛnt/.

For loan words from other languages, such as Spanish, Dutch, Danish, or Russian, the spelling has a larger impact, since most German speakers are not aware of (some aspects of) the native pronunciation.

(*) Actually, it's a slightly extended German phonology that includes a small number of sounds that do not occur in native words, such as /ʒ/, a few nasal vowels, possibly also /w/.

(**) That is, what German speakers perceive as the closest relative. This may not agree with what English or French speakers would consider as the closest relative.

Comment: If the spelling is ignored, why some Germans pronounce Sandwich as /sentvit͡ʃ/ (with the w letter pronounced as /v/) ? German phonology has /w/ (or at least /u/ , which is very similar).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista There is no /w/ in German phonology. There is /ʊ̯/, but only as second part of a diphthong, not as a syllable-initial consonant.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista On the other hand, it's true that the spelling is not completely ignored. That applies for instance to “b” and “v” in Spanish: In Spanish, “b” and “v” are pronounced identically: after a pause or a nasal consonant as a stop, otherwise as a fricative. If Spanish words are imported to German, “b” is always /b/ and “v” is always /v/.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Are you bothered by the /t/ we insert?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No, I was just looking for the logic behind using a mix of English and German pronunciations in those words. This answer made it clear.

Comment: Very well said! This is why we have the sciences of "Füsik" and "Filosofie".

Comment: Brit in Germany here. It drives me mad that Germans pronounce every a they see in English words as ae. Like Diana, becomes Di-enna. And band becomes bend. Sometimes they even spell it bänd. Holy moly. I gather German educators learn the accent from some very old recordings... my son's English teacher told him that I pronounce my own name wrong. Super.

Comment: @redsonja Not sure why it drives you mad. The UK and the US pronounce the A in words like "band" differently and Germans had to pick one of the two; they just didn't pick the one you're more familiar with. On the other hand, they are nearer the UK pronunciation of "computer" (with a /t/) than the US one (with a /ɾ/) .

Comment: @RedSonja Given the seemingly random relation between spelling and pronunciation in English and the differences between English varieties/dialects, that is not surprising at all. As for band becoming bent, this also serves to distinguish it from the german Band (ribbon) and Bande (gang). Maybe the spelling will reflect this difference at some point (Bänd would not be a bad choice). I loathe the pronunciation "dänce" for dance, but it follows simple rules.. so, meh? 
German words in English get mangled as well, for similar reasons.

Comment: I feel compelled to note that German is not unusual in this respect, most languages handle loanwords like this, attempting to preserve pronunciation as much as possible. English is the strange case, with our common insistence on preserving spelling (or mostly preserving spelling, but getting rid of diacritical marks or their equivalents) instead of preserving pronunciation.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista It's probably less a logic of mixing English and German pronunciation rather than merely a German accent trying to pronounce the original English word. As a German with little pronunciation difficulties, working as software developer, and internationally, also privately having plenty of non-German speaking acquaintances, I always go for the same pronunciation as I do in English unless there is a clearly "eingedeutschte" version of the word, e.g. "TV-Serie". I'm absolutely certain most others do the same and not deliberately change the pronunciation between German and English.

Answer (score 13):

Those are inconsistencies introduced by both the speaker not being used to the English pronounciation and overcorrecting it, and you not being used to the variety of German dialects and their somewhat off vowel pronounciation.

The general “rule” is that we try to retain the pronounciation from the foreign language but fail at the attempt. And another “rule” is that we don't spell in the foreign language, so abbreviations follow German spelling.

In particular:

- TV-Serie — must be /te**ː**fauzeːʁiə/ If you heard an /e/ or /i/ for the first vowel, you misheard or that speaker does something very odd.
- Computer — yes, it's /kɔmpjuːtɐ/. That /pj/ does not exist in German so it sticks out and people try to copy it. And getting that thing correct, no one cares about the rest then.
- Band — yes, /bænt/. Typical German Auslautverhärtung. It's a habit. We can't change it, even if we wanted.
- Sandwich — I think this is a bad example because people only use this word when they talk about that comical american version of the Butterbrot. So they mispronounce it on purpose. I do. I say /zantviç/.

Comment: Isn't Butterbrot just one slice of bread with butter? A sandwich always has two slices and other things between them, like cheese and ham. Anyway, I don't understand why people "mispronounce it on purpose"

Comment: No. This https://www.planet-wissen.de/kultur/nordrhein_westfalen/ruhrgebiet/ruhrgebiet-butterbrot-100~_v-gseagaleriexl.jpg is a typical Butterbrot. Looks like a sandwich, doesn't it? But with German bread. Point is that we don't consider American “bread” to be bread. We call that “Toastbrot” instead because the only way it becomes digestable to Germans is by putting it into a toaster. It's not commonly used for Butterbrot in Germany because it soaks too fast so you can't wrap it up for second breakfast at work.

Comment: The third and imho most relevant rule is that you can't look overzealous in using English pronunciation in a German sentence. If you pronounce "Computer" or "Apple Mac" or "Band" like an American in a German sentence as a German native speaker you look like a showoff or nerd.

Comment: I have no idea what @Janka is on about, if you go to a cafe or bakery where I've lived (for me having been BW and Franconia) and ask for a Butterbrot they'll definitely give you a slice of bread with butter. That said most bakeries wouldn't call it a sandwich, it'll be X + name of the bread or Brötchen mit X where X is whatever filling they're putting in. Trendier cafes will often call it a sandwich though because Denglish is seen as the trendy thing to do there. My German friends use either the German or Denglish term depending on the person

Comment: A Butterbrot in Switzerland is just one slice of bread with butter... @Janka, please consider cultural and regional differences before making a statement. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterbrot

Comment: Nun ja, man kann spezifisch und spezifischer werden und ein Mozarellla-Tomaten-Basilikum-Vollkornsandwich offerieren - bei Sandwich würde ich in der Tat einen Deckel erwarten - oder schlicht "Stulle" sagen, was aber weder Mozarellla-Tomaten-Basilikum-Vollkorn, noch den Deckel ausschließt. Und Butterbrot oder schlicht Brot würde ich auch nicht als falsch betrachten. Bestellen würde ich es aber nur, wenn ausgeschlossen ist, dass es sich um ungetoastetes Toast handelt.

Comment: The pronunciation of English abbreviations in German is actually quite unpredictable. Compare “NATO” /ˈnato/, “NASA” /ˈnaza/, “USA” /uːʔɛsˈʔaː/  “FBI” /ɛfbɪˈaɪ̯/, “CIA” /sɪaɪ̯ˈɛɪ̯/.

Comment: @Janka As a swabian, I would definitely not see that Salamibrot there as a Butterbrot. But we have more dialects than I want to bother shaking a stick at, so I'm not *too* surprised that the people in NRW think differently. But if you asked me for a Butterbrot, you'd get bread with butter. If you asked me for a Butterbrot mit Salami, I'd think it a bit strange that you didn't say Salamibrot but give you the right thing.

Comment: @HalvarF That is simply not true. I always use the same pronunciation as I do in English (having little to no German accent) unless there is a clearly Germanized version of the word, and I've never been perceived as "showoff" for that. For other things, maybe, but certainly not for that. Granted, I can't rule out slight changes to ease the pronunciation transition but that would be unintentional. If you "overuse" English words when German equivalents do exist, as in youth or business slang, then yes, but I'd say that's a different topic.

Comment: @Uwe I actually wouldn't consider it to be very unpredictable. Both "FBI" and "CIA" (also "NCIS", "MI5" etc.) are institutions in English speaking countries, which we barely have any contact with. Meanwhile, the NATO is an international organisation, we are even part of, the USA is a country (though it is surprising we keep the English abbreviation at all) and the NASA has often been in the news for decades - actually for so long, our parent and grandparent generations less proficient in English still know them. They've existed before the recent English fancy of younger generations.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher For me, I have a very different pronunciation when saying these words in a German vs. in an English sentence. and it's the same for almost everyone I know. Examples are the first vowels in Computer or Apple,  the -er in Computer or Internet, or the final consonant in Band .

Comment: @HalvarF My comment was more about whether other people would perceive you as showoff if you didn't, which they do not. If anything, quite the contrary, I've received positive remarks in the past but never a negative one. The rest was more my personal way, I wasn't saying others wouldn't have a different pronunciation. Also, Internet does have its own German pronunciation, I would deliberately not pronounce that one the English fashion.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher That was a comment on Janka's remark “another “rule” is that we don't spell in the foreign language”. Sometimes we do.

Comment: @Uwe Well, you literally mentioned "the pronunciation of abbreviations" so I assumed your comment was about that, not the spelling.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher If you had understood what Janka's remark “another “rule” is that we don't spell in the foreign language” referred to, you had understood my comment.

Comment: @Uwe I do understand Janka's remark about German abbreviations following German spelling. Still has nothing to do with your comment about pronunciation, which also isn't as unpredictable as you claim.